# Docker PHP + Rabbit -> Error Connecting to server(99): Cannot assign requested address in

Tags: php, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I have problem with connection PHP (on apache) with RabbitMq. Booth services is running in one cointainer in Docker. I have an error:

Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException: Error Connecting to server(99): Cannot assign requested address in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AMQPStreamConnection.php(21): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->__construct('localhost', '5672', 3, 3, NULL) #1 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/queueProducer.php(12): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection->__construct('localhost', '5672', 'guest', 'guest') #2 {main} thrown in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 27

This is my docker-compose.yml. Could you help me?

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  apache:
    container_name: apache
    build: ./docker/apache
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  php:
    container_name: php
    build: ./docker/php
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    working_dir: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'test'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: helloworld
      MYSQL_USER: helloworld
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'test'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./database/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8085:80
  rabbit1:
      image: rabbitmq:3-management
      hostname: rabbit1
      ports:
          - "5672:5672"
          - "15672:15672"
          - "25672:25672"
secrets:
    erlang_cookie:
        file: ./RabbitConfig/erlang_cookie.txt
```

Comment: Docker compose services are running in separate containers. You have to use the service name as hostname, in your case `rabbit1`. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: The `ports:` spec in docker-compose is mapping those ports to your _computer's_ localhost [FYI: also literally every available interface on your machine] which none of your containers can see. By default docker-compose creates an isolated network that the containers themselves can talk on, and publishes their service names in DNS on that network. So change the hostname in your PHP code from `localhost` to `rabbit1`.

Comment: @CodeSpirit - thanks you! It's working and I don't know how I could have missed it ;)